# Get Spark metrics on each iteration step?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning

Applying spark's logistic regression on a specific dataset requires to define a number of iterations. So far I've learned that outputting the result of the cost function on each iteration might be useful information to plot. It can be used to visualize how many iterations a function needs to converge to a minimum. I was wondering if there is a way to output such information in spark? Looping over a train() function with different iteration numbers, sounds like a solution that requires a lot of time on large datasets. It would be nice to know if there is a better one already built in. Thanks for any advice on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've trained a model (call it **myModel**) that has such a history, you can get the iteration-by-iteration history with

```
myModel.summary.objectiveHistory.foreach(...)
```

There's a nice example [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/ml-linear-methods.html) in the Spark ML documentation -- once you know the right search terms.

Comment: Your solution works fine with spark.ml. Since my implementation of logistic regression uses spark.mllib and there is no such "summary" option available, I guess the only alternative is to change my code.

Comment: Right.  ML Lib has no such facility: it encapsulates the algorithms, and this history is one of the things you don't get to see.